# Running a program with a package

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript, mxml

Can any one tell me if i have saved the following file as test.mxml

If i run the program i get some errors.If we include a class in a package how should the program be run??

```
package {
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.media.*;
public class test  {

    public function Test() {
          //alerting some code
    }
}
}
```

Comment: That doesn't look like XML of any description... and where is Java relevant?

Comment: I believe that is ActionScript, which does look a lot like Java.

Comment: bro, it seems to very hard to understand, wht u want to say.

Comment: If the above program is saved as text.mxml and the above code is Actionscript will the program compile,right now i get some errors.So if a package is declared as above should we save it as test,mxml and run the program or should we save it as .as file??

Comment: This isn't MXML to start with, it is pure ActionScript. Get a basic AS book, really.

Comment: Try doing *public class test extends Sprite {*

Answer (score 0):

You can either have a MXML class that would look something like this
Test.mxml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx" minWidth="955" minHeight="600"
creationComplete="application1_creationCompleteHandler(event)">
<fx:Script>
<![CDATA[
import mx.controls.Alert;
import mx.events.FlexEvent;
protected function application1_creationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
{
   Alert.show("test");
}
]]>
</fx:Script>
</s:Application>
```

Or you can have a pure actionscript class that looks like this:

Test.as

```
package
{
import mx.controls.Alert;

  public class Test
  {
     public function Test()
     {
       Alert.show("Test");
     }
  }
}
```

Comment: In ur Test.as i get an error saying mx.packages not found any clue y?

Comment: Also i get the following error  [root@localhost ~]# mxmlc /tmp/Test.as
Loading configuration file /opt/flex/frameworks/flex-config.xml
/tmp/Test.as: Warning: This compilation unit did not have a factoryClass specified in Frame metadata to load the configured runtime shared libraries. To compile without runtime shared libraries either set the -static-link-runtime-shared-libraries option to true or remove the -runtime-shared-libraries option.

/tmp/Test.swf (465 bytes)

Answer (score 0):

Your problem might be the lower case "t" of your class name and the upper case "T" of its constructor. Otherwise it's not clear what you are asking.